# Modeling a feature like github's per line commenting

Tags: git, design-patterns, mongodb, couchdb

I'm building a system that allows users to create content and edit that content, while maintaining access to all previous versions. In a way, you could think about how StackOverflow allows people to post a question, then edit the question, and still view all previous versions.

However, my users need to be be able to select text in the content and add a comment to that particular text. So instead of adding a comment to an entire blob of content (like in SO), they can target a specific word or phrase in the content and attach a comment to it.

When I display a content blob, I need to show all comments that were ever added to it, regardless of what the current version contains. So if the word or phrase a comment was attached to has been removed, I still need to show the comment, although that comment might indicate somehow that it is not attached in the current version.

[Github](http://github.com/) has a feature that allows members to add a comment to a specific line of source code. This is a fairly close approximation to what I'm wanting to do. However, I believe in Github, the comment is attached only to a specific version of that file. Future versions of that file won't show that comment.

Software like Microsoft Word has features like this too. But my application will be a webapp with collaborative features amongst users, so multiple users can comment on any given content.

I'm considering using a NoSQL solution like CouchDB or MongoDB to store the blobs of content and the comments. Another option is to use git to maintain the content blobs and versioning, but I'm unsure where I'd store the comment information.

Any suggestions on how to best model and store this type of information? How would a comment reference words or phrases in the content? How to best know when a comment is attached to text in the current version or not?

Answer (score 0):

You could model in a way where you have a file (or any other suitable object that can hold meta data, e.g. in a database) for each comment made by a user, and create a certain naming convention where you combine the file name of the file being commented on, the SHA1 of the blob and an index for multiple comments on each file. So for each file foo, you could have something like:

```
foo-blob1-0
foo-blob1-1
foo-blob1-2
foo-blob1-3
foo-blob2-0
..
foo-blobm-0
..
foo-blobm-n
```

When a new revision of the file has been commited there will be a new blob (or possibly an old blob showing up again, since previous versions of the file might be identical due to add and remove of text) that people can comment on. The objects obviously also need to know the range of the text being commented on.